# Would quantum computers affect the C++ language?

Tags: c++, portability, quantum-computing

The advent of quantum computers could still be decades from now. Nevertheless, because software gets incredibly complex these days, it would be good to know if C++, one of the most used programming languages to develop such software, is able to project itself into the future  where quantum computing is a norm and, in addition to portability across platforms, ensure portability of such software over decades.

Comment: There's `std::qvector`, whose member function `empty()` returns a `qbool`. The vector's state is only determined after you read that bool.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Don't forget `qbegin()`, `cqbegin()`, `cqrbegin()`, `qend()`, `cqend()` and `cqrend()`.

Comment: yes there will be a future of c++ on quantum computer , check this project http://web.archive.org/web/20090620011647/http://sra.itc.it:80/people/serafini/qlang/

Answer (score 7):

Quantum computing will never be "the norm". It's not suitable for everything. It's suitable for solving some problems that are intractible with conventional algorithms, but we won't just be throwing it at everything, running our little C++ utilities on quantum computers.

So, no, I don't think so.